# What is the MVVM way of loading images in list in Android?

Tags: architecture, android, mvvm

**Scenario:**
A very simple android app needed to be developed. It has just one screen with a list of items. Each item has a label and an icon. We fetch the item list from the server, and the server response contains labels and URLs of icons. `ViewModel` asks `Repository` for the list, the `View` observers the list reference in `ViewModel` to update the UI whenever there is a change. The view uses an `Adapter` to populate the data into `ListView`. The adapter is aware of the items are on the screen so it can render only those, plus a few more which are going to appear next.

**Problem:**
Where in that whole scenario should the images be downloaded from URLs?

**Solution 1 (bad):** We fetch the images in `ViewModel` and pass the `image data` along with labels. `View` and `Adapter` won't have to know about the image fetching mechanism, but we will need to download all images even if there are 1000. Because `ViewModel` is not aware of which items are on the screen. Implementation in adapter would be something like this:

```
currentView.iconHolder.image = list[position].iconImageData
```

**Solution 2 (somewhat bad):** Instead of adding the `image data` to the model, `ViewModel` adds a reference to `ImageLoader` to the `Model` objects resulting in something like `LoadableImage`. The adapter can use that reference to trigger image loading for the items it decides.

```
list[position].loadableImage.getBitmap { bitmap -> 
    currentView.iconHolder.image = bitmap
}
```

The drawback is, we have an unrelated reference in the model classes.

**Solution 3 (Ok):**
We pass/inject `ImageLoader` to `Adapter` itself. We use it to fetch the images from URLs.

```
imageLoader.getBitmap(list[position].iconUrl, onBitmapDownloaded: { bitmap ->
  currentView.iconHolder.image = bitmap
})
```

The only problem is, the view needs to know about `ImageLoader`.

Is there a better solution than **Solution 3**?

Answer (score 1):

Architecture wise `Solution 1` follows separation of concerns much better so it is actually the best if you can limit the amount of images downloaded at one time, *(you shouldn't have to download all images at once)*. You should look into Pagination. Here is an article that might help you get started. https://www.raywenderlich.com/12244218-paging-library-for-android-with-kotlin-creating-infinite-lists

You pull a certain amount to display to the screen as they scroll you pull more. And your concern about not knowing what is displayed, that is rectified by the `DiffUtil` also seen in the link. The adapter knows what it has if you feed it duplicate data it will just ignore it.

**NOW** if you really truly can't limit the amount of images you have to download at once then `Solution 3` is your next best alternative. But it is still a big problem, because say the image count is in the ten of thousands now. **10,000** url `Strings` is still **10,000** objects. `Solution 3` will eventually fall apart.

Comment: Thanks for this link. About your objection on solution 3: the app will fall apart on repository layer in this case if there is more data than device memory. I would say that is not a problem in current scope of the question.